# Is there a way for me to round the float value to 4 decimals places generated by this percentile function? [MS-SQL SERVER]

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, median, percentile

SELECT DISTINCT
percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Number) OVER()
FROM TABLE

Comment: are you trying to generate percentile result ?

Comment: Yes, but what I'm trying to achieve is to get a median. The percentile function gives me the same answer but I want to round it off to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a single value, I'm not sure why you are expressing this as a table.  I would expect code like this:

```
DECLARE @median NUMERIC(20, 4);

SELECT TOP (1) @median = round(percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Number) OVER(), 4)
FROM @table;

SELECT @median;
```

Comment: Tysm, this solved my problem. I was actually making quite a few syntax mistakes using round and variable declaration. Also, you're right and I've edited to not SELECT the whole table and just one value. 
Thanks again!